# Twitter Bootstrap : Not able to download master from Github

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, download

I've been trying to download the file https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/archive/master.zip from Github for 2-3 days now. But in the middle of the download I get this error

"File could not be saved, because the source file could not be read. Try again later, or contact the server administrator."

At first I thought this was a temporary glitch. But 2-3 days down the line, i'm sure there is something I am missing.

Have you ever faced this problem? If so, do you know how to solve it? I tried switching off all my firewalls - but i still cant download the fie…

Can you please help?

Comment: I just did a `wget https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/archive/master.zip` and it went through successfully. Also, just clicking on the link downloaded a successful zip to my folder. Make sure you download it to a location where you have write permissions to